# How to create a 301 redirect for new product URL in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following problem.

My website has changed the CMS and the product URLS are different. They used to look like this:

```
domain.com/old-link/?a1=291&b2=23&c3=92
```

The new one however looks like this:

```
domain.com/new-one/291-23-92
```

How can I create a redirect for all products that look like that using .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited it. I've tried RedirectMatch but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /old-link/\?a1=([^&]+)&b2=([^&]+)&c3=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new-link/%1-%2-%3? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect, I've also added R=301.